# Triggers on specifc applications in Keyboard Maestro

Tags: productivity, keybindings

How can I tell Keyboard Maestro to only enable a given trigger (e.g. a hot key) when a specific application is active?

For example, I would like a specific macro/hotkey that pastes without formatting to only be active when I am editing a document in Word or TextEdit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create a Macro Group (File → New Macro Group or ⌘⇧N).
2. Set the Macro Group to only be available in certain applications:

   [image]
   [image]
3. Drag macros to the macro group.